# It is posible to expand a JTextArea or JTextPane by clicking on it?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, jtextpane

i'm trying to do an aplication but i don't know if is posible to do something like this, for example:[image]

So the **rectangle** is the  JTextArea (or JTextPane) and it has a fixed zise, that's why are the suspension points, but when i clikc on it like this:

[image]

we got the expansion of JTextArea(or JTextPane), but when the focus is losted it will come back at the begining:

[image]

The text can be anything , so when the text is too long, automatically add "..." at the end

Comment: Yes, it's possible, maybe have a look at the `setRows` method of `JTextArea`.  `JTextPane` would be more tricky

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `CardLayout` and the focusable `JLabel` instead of `JTextField` in order to use the default `JLabel` truncate feature:

[image: screenshot]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TextAreaExpandTest {
  private static final String TEXT =
    "The text can be anything, so when the text is too long," +
    " automatically add '...' at the end.";
  public JComponent makeUI() {
    CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
    JPanel cp = new JPanel(cardLayout);

    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(TEXT, 5, 10) {
      @Override public void updateUI() {
        super.updateUI();
        setLineWrap(true);
        setWrapStyleWord(true);
        setMargin(new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1));
      }
    };

    JLabel textField = new JLabel(" ") {
      @Override public void updateUI() {
        super.updateUI();
        setOpaque(true);
        setFocusable(true);
        setBackground(UIManager.getColor("TextField.background"));
        setForeground(UIManager.getColor("TextField.foreground"));
        setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("TextField.border"));
      }
    };

    textArea.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
      @Override public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
        String text = textArea.getText();
        textField.setText(text.isEmpty() ? " " : text);
        cardLayout.show(cp, "TextField");
      }
    });
    textField.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
      @Override public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
        cardLayout.show(cp, "TextArea");
        textArea.requestFocusInWindow();
      }
    });
    textField.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
      @Override public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        cardLayout.show(cp, "TextArea");
        textArea.requestFocusInWindow();
      }
    });
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    panel.add(textField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(
      textArea,
      ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER,
      ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    cp.add(panel, "TextField");
    cp.add(scroll, "TextArea");

    JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    p.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(32, 32, 32, 32));
    p.add(cp, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    p.add(new JButton("focus dummy"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    return p;
  }
//   //TEST: JTextArea"setRows(...)
//   public JComponent makeUI2() {
//     JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
//     JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("", 1, 10);
//     textArea.setLineWrap(true);
//     textArea.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
//       @Override public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
//         JTextArea ta = (JTextArea) e.getComponent();
//         ta.setRows(8);
//         p.revalidate();
//       }
//       @Override public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
//         JTextArea ta = (JTextArea) e.getComponent();
//         ta.setRows(1);
//         p.revalidate();
//       }
//     });
//     JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(
//       textArea,
//       ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER,
//       ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
//     p.add(scroll, BorderLayout.NORTH);
//     p.add(new JButton("focus dummy"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
//     p.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
//     return p;
//   }
  public static void main(String... args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
      UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);
      JFrame f = new JFrame();
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      f.getContentPane().add(new TextAreaExpandTest().makeUI());
      f.setSize(320, 240);
      f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      f.setVisible(true);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a JPanel to add and remove [JTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html) and [JTextArea](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) with [FocusListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/focuslistener.html)

[image]
[image]

For one line input use JTextField and to add "..." you need to implement [KeyListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) interface.

Use a global flag that will set whenever you GainFocus on JTextField. A thread will check for this flag and if it is set then it will remove the JTextField object from JPanel and add JTextArea with saved String.

OR

You can implement FocusListner to JPanel instead of more complicated thread thing.

Answer (score 0):

Everything depends on the layout you are using. What I would do would be to use a layout the respects the preferredSize of its components. Then I would change the preferredSize of the JTextPane given a Boolean parameter (expanded or not expanded).

When I say change the preferredSize, I mean override the getPreferredSize method.